# ruby logic for getting first image of each listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `listing model`. Each listing has `many` images. So in my `index` page I want to display all listings and the first image of each listing. So in controller I first fetch all listings which has all fields like `:name`, `:`description, `etc`. Now for the images part is where am stuck. How can I properly add the :`custom_url` field with the `image url` in each room using `ruby` code?

> (NB: I am using angular on front end so this is just for the json and
>   dont want to add a seperate field in database for the first image)

So here is the controller code

```
 def search
    @listings = Listing.all


      custom_url = listing.photos[0].image_url(:medium)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {listings: @listings} }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Listing model add a method that gets the image url and call it `custom_url`

**Listing.rb**

```
def custom_url
    photos.first.image_url(:medium)
end
```

Then in the `render_json` include the method `custom_url`:

```
def search
  @listings = Listing.all
  listings_json = @listings.as_json({methods: :custom_url}

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {listings: listings_json }
  end
end
```

Comment: As an aside maybe rewrite as `photos.first.image_url(:medium)` no need to use self and first is more readable than [0]